# Want to avoid Add to Cart or Checkout page and want direct paypal payment method

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

Dear developers I am creating a website for online events. In this when a user ll register for a event I want user to pay $25 by paypal then its registration form ll be completed.

I simple and easy way to process paypal payment system to pay $25 by the user at the time of filling registration form, and complete the registration process.
Here I want

1. paypal button.(which paypal method ll be better)
2. As I want simple payment system without proper Add to cart or Checkout page

How I ll get confirmation "$25 has been paid successfully" so that we confirm the registration process?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a simple $25 smart payment or buy now button via https://www.paypal.com/buttons

The more complicated part is tying such a button to your registration form and process. Will the user enter their registration details before payment, or after payment? How will a successful payment be reconciled with a successfully submitted form? Automating this smoothly is a web development task and requires programming knowledge.